# Turn on torch during ARSession

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, flashlight

How could I turn on the flashlight (torch) during an ARSession?

The standard code, does not work, as as soon the session starts with  the flashlight is turned off.

Initializing the ARSession:

```
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        self.sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: [.removeExistingAnchors])
```

Function to turn on/off the flashlight:

```
private func turnTorch(enabled: Bool) {
    guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video) else {
        return // Cant initiate avcapturedevice error
    }

    if device.hasTorch {
        do {
            try device.lockForConfiguration()

            if enabled {
                device.torchMode = .on
            } else {
                device.torchMode = .off
            }

            device.unlockForConfiguration()
        } catch {
            return //Torch could not be used, lock for configuration failed
        }

    } else {
        return // Torch not available error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are trying to turn on the flashlight (torch) some time before your session has run.
Using SceneKit, I tried this approach and worked fine for me:

First, add this variable to your class to know when your flashlight (torch) is on or off:

```
var isTorchOn = false
```

Next, implement `ARSCNViewDelegate`'s `didRenderScene` method and when the session is ready, turn on the flashlight there.  Since this delegate is executed each frame, you need to use `isTorchOn` there to run your flashlight method only once.

Also, notice that I've added the `isTorchOn` flag inside your `turnTorch` method to update its value.

The final and simplified code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!

    var isTorchOn = false

    private func turnTorch(enabled: Bool) {
        guard let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video) else {
            return // Cant initiate avcapturedevice error
        }

        if device.hasTorch {
            do {
                try device.lockForConfiguration()

                if enabled {
                    device.torchMode = .on
                } else {
                    device.torchMode = .off
                }
                self.isTorchOn = enabled // *** Add this line! ***

                device.unlockForConfiguration()
            } catch {
                return
            }

        } else {
            return
        }
    }

    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didRenderScene scene: SCNScene, atTime time: TimeInterval) {
        if self.sceneView.session.currentFrame != nil {
            if !isTorchOn {
                turnTorch(enabled: true)
            }
        }
    }

    func sessionWasInterrupted(_ session: ARSession) {
        // Probably you would want to turn the torch off here.
    }

    func sessionInterruptionEnded(_ session: ARSession) {
        // Probably you would want to turn the torch on again here.
    }

}
```

You can follow the same approach if you're using SpriteKit.

Comment: Yes! You are correct, the problem was that I was trying to turn it on just before the session started to run.

Thank you!